# Android Save object as blob in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview

is this right. I have this `gridview`. I want to save its item as blob in sqlite. so when i open the list of save data in sqlite ill just load the save `items` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` to my `gridview`

I tried this one but I get `NotSerializableException` error

List items = new ArrayList();

```
public static byte[] serializeObject(Object o) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            out.writeObject(o);
            out.close();

            // Get the bytes of the serialized object
            byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();

            return buf;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("serializeObject", "error", ioe);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

my insert row

```
public long insertRow(byte[] data) {
    /*
     * CHANGE 3:
     */
    // TODO: Update data in the row with new fields.
    // TODO: Also change the function's arguments to be what you need!
    // Create row's data:
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATA, data);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

then I insert the serialize object

```
myDB.insertRow(MyDBAdapter.serializeObject(items));
```

also i'm confuse. should i save the adapter or the list of items'?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The way I store data as BLOB in my DB, is by converting them to JSON and then storing the bytes.
e.g.

```
ArrayList<Person> persons  = new ArrayList<>();
Gson gson = new Gson();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MyProvider.KEY_DATA, gson.toJson(persons).getBytes());
// insert or update the DB
```

And to get the list back

```
byte[] blob = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyProvider.KEY_DATA));
String json = new String(blob);
Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<Person> persons = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Person>>()
                                 {}.getType());
```

Edit: to answer your last question, you should store your data (list of items).

Comment: What do you mean? How to store a list of items? Or how to get them back?

Comment: Edited the answer to demonstrate how to get them back :)

Comment: Since the data is json, is there any benefit to saving to the DB as a blob rather than as just text? Asking because I'm also storing json to a DB.

Comment: @Redshirt Well this question is quite old. I have long since abandoned storing json as blob due to it not having any bennefits. With that being said, the question was about saving an object as a BLOB, so I haven't modified my answer.

Comment: I get ------->  (Method threw 'android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException' exception) in this zone : cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(nameObject)

Comment: I think that not work the insert, and I get Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Answer (score 0):

instead of `(Object o)`, pass `(Serializable o)`. Then, in the stuff you pass, add `implements Serializable` to class definition.