# Save object to sqlite db

Tags: android, database, serializable

I want to save a class object to db. I used Serializable but one of objects in my class always is null.

```
 import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 public class A implements Serializable {
 protected String Name;
 protected int Type;
 protected transient List<LatLng> Nodes=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
```

}

nodes is always  null. If I remove 'transient' then all of objects become null.

Save to db is like this:

```
    public long InsertList(A Data) {

    byte[] bytes = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        oos.writeObject(Data);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        bos.close();
        bytes = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //TODO: Handle the exception
        ex.printStackTrace();
        ;
    }

    ContentValues insertValues = new ContentValues();
    insertValues.put("Data", bytes);
    insertValues.put("Selected", 1);
    return mDb.insert("Table", null, insertValues);

}
```

Comment: Why don't you migrate to Realm database?

Comment: @MohammedAtif I have no problem with sqlite. My major problem is nodes object is always null.

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243181/how-to-store-object-in-sqlite-database

Comment: Please show how you save the object to the database.

Comment: Check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577825/android-save-object-as-blob-in-sqlite

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Added

Comment: Remember that all code in Java must be in a class. Also most code is also in a method. Please show these with your code snippets.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added full class. See it plz.

Answer (score 1):

The transient keyword in Java is used to indicate that a field should not be serialized.

So nodes will not be serialized in your case.

check out this [Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields)

Comment: Why nodes is null?

Comment: @FarzadShahbazi because transient fields are not serialized. Therefore it cannot be unmarshalled.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Why nothing saved to db if I remove transient field?

Comment: @FarzadShahbazi Have you checked for exceptions while serializing your object? [Check details for Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/exceptions.html)

Comment: @a.r. I have no exeption.

Comment: @FarzadShahbazi LatLng is not Serializable