# I want to save an object with dynamic attributes as byte[] or raw data in Sqlite and load it as an Object from Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I don't want to use any ORM or Realm, and also I do not prefer to convert my data to Json like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577825/android-save-object-as-blob-in-sqlite).

My class is simple now but I want to extend it in future.

```
public class Request implements Serializable {
    public int Id;
    public int Type;
    public int MTI;
    public String amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. First, convert your Object into raw data with requestClassToRawData() method, then save it to Sqlite.

```java
public static byte[] requestClassToRawData(Request request) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
            oos.writeObject(request);
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

Then you can convert it back to your Object with rawDataTORequestClass() method later.

```java
public static Request rawDataTORequestClass(byte[] data) {
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
            return (Request ) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: This is going to take up more space than JSON, it will be slower, it will have difficulty upgrading in the future, and you will not be able to debug the data manually.

Comment: I want to choose this for save logs in database.

Comment: this is not working beacuse POJO is not serializable.